How to implement jetified external library in Android Studio
I need to implement 2 external libraries, and i copied them from another cache. For implementing single file jar and aar i use
android {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation(name: 'example_name', ext: 'aar')
}

The 2 libraries are in jetified format:
jar(folder)
res(folder)
AndroidManifest.xml
R.txt
jar folder contains Classes.jar
How can i implement them.
